# How can I generate an empty class based on a table in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table in codeigniter with the rows `id, name,` and `email`. I have one view that I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<input name='name' value='<?= $record->name; ?>' />
<input name='name' value='<?= $record->email; ?>' />
```

I'd also like to use the form on new and empty records. is there a way to use CodeIgniters db class to generate an empty stdClass with the structure of a db result, so that this code does not throw a bunch of notices & errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default solution to this. You either have to populate the object yourself with all the (empty) properties or just check if the property exists.

```
<input name='name' value='<?= isset($record->email) ? $record->email : ''; ?>' />
```

Don't forget to run `form_prep()` on those `value`s.

If you want to try this, you could create a dummy class.

```
class DB_Record {
    function __get($prop) {
        return isset($this->$prop) ? $this->$prop : NULL;
    }
}
```

Then have your records be an instance of it:

```
$record = new DB_Record;
// fetch data from your database and assign to properties of $record
```

Then when an inaccessible property is accessed, it will just return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

try this, where **teams** is a table name:

```
$r = new stdClass();
foreach ($this->db->field_data('teams') as $f) {
  $r->{$f->name} = '';  
}
```

I.E: teams is MySQL table with fields: TeamName, Location, State

$r will be Object like:

```
$r->TeamName = ''
$r->Location = ''
$r->State = ''
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing i think you can do is like that you use the set_value function from the form_helper so that your code will be changed to :

```
<input name='name' value='<?= set_value('name', $record->name); ?>' />
<input name='email' value='<?= set_value('email',$record->email); ?>' />
```

you can read more about the form_helper at [from_helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: I think you missed the point, OP is most likely getting `trying to access property of non object` errors because `$record` doesn't have any properties (or maye isn't defined) when adding a new entry.

Comment: thats right @Madmartigan , if he want to use it on a new record all he has to do is just to create the `$record` object and add the two fields like : `$record->name = '';` and `$record->email = ''`, unless i did miss the point again